# What's the best way to resolve IndexError issue?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a program to generate an output, but I ran into an IndexError with the following line;

```
X_out[index_1, index_2, X_subset] = 1
```

below is the error I got;

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 20
     18 index_1 = np.repeat(np.arange(batch_size), seq_len).reshape(batch_size, seq_len)
     19 index_2 = np.arange(seq_len)
---> 20 X_out[index_1, index_2, X_subset] = 1

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I need help to resolve this issue. Here is my code;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

batch_size=2
vocab_size=2

n_samples = len(df['Name'])
seq_len = len(df['Name'][0])
X=df['Name']
Y=df['Age']
start = 0       
stop = start + batch_size
X_subset = X[start: stop]
X_out = np.zeros([batch_size, seq_len, vocab_size])
index_1 = np.repeat(np.arange(batch_size), seq_len).reshape(batch_size, seq_len)
index_2 = np.arange(seq_len)
X_out[index_1, index_2, X_subset] = 1
```

Comment: `X_subset` is a Pandas dataframe, you can't use it as an index into a numpy array.

Comment: `X_subset` contains names -- how are those supposed to be used as indexes into the `X_out` array? What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your last X_out command?

Comment: I suspect you just want to use `start:stop` there instead of `X_subset`

Comment: I am trying to create a data generator to send batches of data to my NN model. The code I have posted was a way for me to find the issue.

Comment: What ever you are trying to do, the indices have to match the listed types.  The only way to 'resolve' the error is to correct  this error, most likely this one derived from the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[142], line 18
     16 index_1 = np.repeat(np.arange(batch_size), seq_len).reshape(batch_size, seq_len)
     17 index_2 = np.arange(seq_len)
---> 18 X_out[index_1, index_2, X_subset] = 1

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Looking at the variables in the problem line:

```
In [143]: X_out.shape
Out[143]: (2, 3, 2)
In [144]: index_1
Out[144]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [145]: index_2
Out[145]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

So far ok.  But:

```
In [146]: X_subset
Out[146]: 
0       Tom
1    Joseph
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

That is clearly not a valid index.  It's a Series, with object type, string values.

`index_1` is (2,3); `index_2` is (3,); they broadcast together, and select all elements in the first 2 dimensions.

```
X_out[index_1, index_2, :]
```

is a valid indexing; selecting all of `X_out`.  Sames `X_out[:]`

`index_1` could just as well be a (2,1) shape; no need for the repeat.

```
In [155]: np.arange(batch_size)[:,None]
Out[155]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])
```

I have no idea what this last `vocab_size` dimension index should be.  Clearly not a Series of words.

With the others being (2,3) and (3,), it can only be (3,) or scalar.  But if `[0,1,0]`, what would the repeat values do?  It can't be `[0,1]`.

```
X_out[index_1, index_2, index_1]=3
```

is ok; again with the (2,3) and (3,) broadcasting.